# Запуск файлов директории

Tags: linux, bash

Задача такая, нужно запустить все исполняемые файлов в каталоге. Каталог вводится в качестве параметра. Нужно учесть возможность рекурсии когда запускаемый сценарий находится в том же каталоге. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В чем проблема? Перебирать файлы в цикле `for` умеете? Про синтаксис `if` читали? Тогда осталось только воспользоваться командой `basename $0`  для "отлова" себя (и может быть почитать man test для написания выражения в `if`, которое будет отбирать только исполнимые regular (т.е. обычные) файлы от всех остальных)

Comment: Да это все понятно, но как это все в bash скрипте написать?

Comment: Ну, `for i in .* *;  do` перебирает файлы, `if [ "$i" == "$ME" ]; then continue fi` отследит себя `if [ -f "$i" -a -x "$i" ]` выбирает исполнимые regular... Теперь попробуйте сами написать (обилие отладочных echo вам поможет)

Answer (score 2):

Для этого нужно воспользоваться утилитой **find**. Знак доллара с последующей единицей используется для указания в параметрах каталога поиска. Поиск рекурсивый по всем директориям. Если такое нежелательно, добавьте опцию `-maxdepth 1` перед списком условий.

```
find "$1" -executable -not -type d -not -samefile "$0" -exec {} \;
```

**Полезное чтение:**

- [find(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/find.1.html)
- [bash(1)](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=bash) {раздел «Позиционные параметры»}
- [Статью на Википедии про find](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/find)

Comment: А где же учет возможной рекурсии?

Comment: А можете объяснить, что делают параметры -not -type d -exec {} \; ?

Comment: @avp, она учтена — файл будет запущен

Comment: @ВадимМороз, `-not -type d` — исключить директории, выполнять их невозможно; `-exec {} \;` — запустить файл на выполнение

Comment: Так сам скрипт рекурсивно запускать **не надо** (это же очевидно, если у вас нет цели подвесить систему)

Comment: @avp, и в самом деле \*genius\*

Comment: подравил, чтобы сам себя не запускал

Comment: хотя и в предыдущем варианте бесконечно рекурсии не было, но выводилась ошибка от **find** об отсутствии каталога с пустым именем — параметры же не передавались